# Force WP to ignore multiple whitespaces

Tags: editor

Is it possible to force WP to ignore multiple whitespaces so in the frontend so there’s only one visible?

It’s because when my client  writes something in the editor  sometimes he enters  two spaces instead of one  and doesn’t notice  that.

I was quite confused about the fact that multiple whitespaces aren’t ignored automatically because in the source code there is a double whitespace `"  "` which to my mind is ignored by all browsers, not `" &nbsp;"` or `&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of a global setting to do this but you have a few options.

Use add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' ) and replace the double spaces. Generally a bad idea because you'd have to account for the valid use of double spaces.

Install a plugin like 'After the Deadline' or similar that shows spelling and typo errors. Of course you can't force the user to accept the changes/corrections.